# Response return from cache but call still made in background to update the cache

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

I am working on spring boot project and calling thirdparty REST API using 
RestTemplate. 
I need following mechanism of cache.

When RestTemplate (client) send a request to Thirdparty REST APIs with booking ID (abc) then its resulting response is cached and deliver to client.

When next time client request the booking ID (abc) it return from cache to client but on background It still send request to ThirdParty API and update the response cache so later the client get the updated result.

Can anyone guide me What cache type is that and is there anyway to do it. Or provide by any Cache Third Party.

I don't want to do raw implementation myself.

Comment: What's the point if the database is anyway going to be loaded with the same volume (and first time fetches will always be affected)? Nonetheless, maybe your best option is to use a cache listener that updates the entry on each hit...

Comment: I am talking about the Rest API call no database is invloved.

Comment: True - yet the comment still applies. Problem is it seems that you're not concerned with either consistency or load on your backend (just quick result, even if it's inconsistent...)?

Comment: There is no issue if, for one request the data is old but on next request it will be latest one.

Comment: I don't know of a cache model that updates asynchronously. So I think you can use listeners to refresh the cache in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You look for a cache feature called *refresh ahead*. Here you find documentation for the various caches:

- For EHCache, there is information in [Terracotta BigMemory Max Documentation - Refresh Ahead](http://ww1.terracotta.org/documentation/4.1/bigmemorymax/api/refresh-ahead)
- For [cache2k](https://cache2k), your can find the documentaiton in the [cache2k user guide](https://cache2k.org/docs/1.0/user-guide.html#refresh-ahead). You can use cache2k currently via the JCache support in Spring Boot
- For caffeine, the documentation is in the [wiki](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Refresh), you can use caffeine directly in Spring Boot

The semantics differ slightly between the implementations. caffeine acts as you describe in your question. After a time interval is passed a request returns the current cache value and a background refresh is triggers. In cache2k a background refresh is triggered when the time interval is passed, to guarantee that a value is no older than a certain duration.